# does Messenger Class usage replace AIDL services

Tags: android, android-service

Is Messenger class an alternative of AIDL in building & consuming remote services
and if so does messenger  handle thread safety for methods i will associated with custom commands of the handler messages? sure no, 
and the service keep track which client needs which method (thread safe methods)but the 
sample here for remote service http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample
made me confused?

Answer (score 0):

> Is Messenger class an alternative of AIDL in building & consuming remote services

To an extent, yes. It is a bit like asking if a rowboat is an alternative for a yacht.

> if so does messenger handle thread safety for methods i will associated with custom commands of the handler messages?

The `handleMessage()` method of your `Handler` will be called on the main application thread.